# Can anyone spot this error in my equation array?

Tags: r, arrays, r-markdown, equation

````
```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} M_x(t) &=& \frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}               \\
\frac{d}{dt} M_x(t) &=& p \frac {d}{dt}\frac{e^t}{1-(1-p)e^t} \\
\frac{d}{dt} M_x(t) &=& p \frac{(\frac{d}{dt}e^t)             \\          
(1-(1-p)e^t)-e^t(\frac{d}{dt} 1-(1-p)e^t)}{(1-(1-p)e^t)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
```
````

This keeps returning the error

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
```

The issue seems to be in the 3rd line because I can knit the first to just fine. However, I cannot find an error in the code and it looks fine between $$.

Comment: This belongs to https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The last frac line has unbalanced parantheses.

Answer (score 0):

You inserted a line break `\\` inside a `frac` in the 3rd to 4th line. It should be:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} M_x(t) &=& \frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}               \\
\frac{d}{dt} M_x(t) &=& p \frac {d}{dt}\frac{e^t}{1-(1-p)e^t} \\
\frac{d}{dt} M_x(t) &=& p \frac{(\frac{d}{dt}e^t)(1-(1-p)e^t)-e^t(\frac{d}{dt} 1-(1-p)e^t)}{(1-(1-p)e^t)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
```